# detect-secrets and reviewdog action not syncing up

Tags: github-actions, token

Any insight into why my local `detect-secrets scan` command is finding a secret, but the review doc action isn't picking it up?

`main.tf`

```
provider "github" {
  token = "ghr_MTIabceIzZHVtbXl0b2tlbjEyMzEyMzEyMwo=" # not real don't worry
}
```

`detect-secrets scan`
[image]

GH Action Run
[image]

`secret-scanning.yml` for reference

```
name: Run detect-secrets with reviewdog
run-name: Detect Secrets
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  secrets-check:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: check for secrets
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Run detect-secrets with reviewdog
        uses: reviewdog/action-detect-secrets@v0.11.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `push` event whereas you should be using `pull_request` for this action to work.

Change `push` to `pull_request`, create a PR and it should work fine.

Also, observe its [inputs](https://github.com/reviewdog/action-detect-secrets#inputs) and their defaults e.g. `filter_mode`, `fail_on_error`, `reporter`, etc. You may configure these according to your use case.

With this `main.tf`:

```
provider "github" {
    token1 = "ghp_MabcfMTIzZHVtbXl0b2tlbjEyMzEyMzEyMwo="
    token2 = "ghr_MTIabceIzZHVtbXl0b2tlbjEyMzEyMzEyMwo="
    token3 = "accf30ed92f4c139e9ea2d255e4c8606fbca2651"
}
```

and, this workflow:

```yaml
name: reviewdog_test

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout [${{ github.repository }}]
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Run detect-secrets with reviewdog
        uses: reviewdog/action-detect-secrets@v0.11.5
```

it fails with the same errors as the CLI:

[image: errors]